# Can I use @Validated and @RequestBody together?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3

I began to study SpringMVC.

This is a method in my Controller.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Result login(@Validated(UserLoginVaildator.class)
@RequestBody User user, BindingResult result, HttpSession session,
    HttpServletResponse response, Model model)
```

I want to use JSR-303 validation to vlidate the user.
And the user is posted by JSON, so I must use `@RequstBody`.

But there is an exception when I try to use this method.

```
Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute. 
Check your handler method signature!
```

I am using spring 3.1.3.RELEASE.

How can I slove this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JSR-303 validation groups (@Validated) + @RequestBody is already supported in spring 3.1.x.

All I know is that @Valid works with @RequestBody. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#new-in-3.1-mvc-valid-requestbody

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start using the latest 3.2GA release?
3.2 supports BindingResult parameter after the @Validated payload.